# Self-referential tables with polymorphism in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm having issues with my model right now. I came across these two ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863336/creating-self-referential-tables-with-polymorphism-in-sqlalchemy)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975793/multiple-self-referential-relationships-in-sqlalchemy)) questions which helped me a lot, but now I'm stuck. Here's my current code:

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column('type', String(10))
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now())
    updated = Column(TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now())
    poster_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    poster = relationship('Person', backref=backref('posts'))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

class Comment(Post):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'comment', 'inherit_condition': (id == Post.id)}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('post.id'), primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('post.id'))
    post = relationship('Post', primaryjoin=('Comment.post_id == Post.id'), backref=backref('comments'), remote_side='Post.id')
    text = Column(Text)
```

The current error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: int is not list-like
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you posted the trace back for the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` is a really unfortunate name for a column;  `id` is a built-in function, and so it's *always* defined.  If you had chosen a less mainstream name for your primary keys, you would be seeing a different error and it would be obvious;

```
class Comment(Post):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'comment', 'inherit_condition': (id == Post.id)}
#                                                                               ^^
```

That `id` refers to `__builtins__.id`, which is a function that returns the address of a python object.  Probably not what you meant.

Easy solution: move `__mapper_args__` below the line where you alias `id` to mean your actual table Column.